# interpreting linear minimum mean squared geometrically

Tags: estimation, prediction, kalman-filter

LMMSE approach estimates $x$ as 
$$\hat{x} = \mathbb{E}[xz^H]\mathbb{E}[zz^H]^{-1}z$$
where $z$ is an observation and a function of $x$.

However, $\hat{x}$ can be interpreted as a projection of $x$ onto $z$:

$$\hat{x} = Proj(x|z) = \langle x, z \cdot (||z||_2)^{-1} \rangle (||z||_2)^{-1} \cdot z$$
and since $||z||_2^2 = \mathbb{E}[zz^H]$, we can rewrite it as
$$=\mathbb{E}[xz^H]\mathbb{E}[zz^H]^{-1}z$$

How is $||z||_2^2 = \mathbb{E}[zz^H]$ when $zz^H$ is an outer product?

Comment: You could answer this question yourself, I believe, simply by carefully writing down the dimensions of all the vectors and matrices involved.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is how is an L2 norm squared(which is a scalar) be the same as an expected value of a matrix?

Comment: $zz^H$ has to be a $1\times 1$ matrix.  It cannot possibly be larger, for then its inverse would not exist: for nonzero $z$, its rank is $1$. I suspect you might be thinking $z$ is a column vector, whereas the formula for $\hat x$ works only if all vectors are row vectors.

Comment: I am pretty certain that $z$ is a column vector. That is why I'm so confused. The proof I wrote down from class says that $z$ is a column vector, and $zz^H$ is the linear space that we want to project our $x$ onto. I believe the prof abused some notations but made clear that $z$ was a column vector.

Comment: It is difficult to interpret "$zz^H$" as a linear space: it's a *matrix.*  When $z$ is a column vector, this is a matrix that projects the entire space of column vectors onto the subspace generated by $z$.  When the entire space is of dimension greater than $1$, obviously this projection is not invertible. When $z$ is not fixed, but has a sufficiently dispersed distribution, taking expectations makes this problem go away, so perhaps your professor has at some point made some such assumptions intended to resolve these issues.